# Why is there such a long delay between casting votes and them registering on your summary tab?

Tags: bug, profile-page, voting, caching

I go into the Home tab and look over many different questions. On some, I vote but I have noticed a significant delay between voting and the vote registering in my Profile/Summary page.

For example, say I have 100 votes when I first login for the day. Then I go and vote say 5 times in 20 minutes. The votes do not show up in your profile for quite some time. It will remain at 100 votes for a significant amount of time before registering that you voted on questions or answers.

Has anyone else noticed this? Does it only register votes x times an hour? Is there a purpose for this?

To clarify, I have noticed this across multiple sites including both Stack Overflow and Meta Stack.

Comment: My guess is that what is in that display box is not synced at each page refresh, it's a way to save db IO. As in your activity feed, in all action, votes, you see the vote in term of second appearing.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com. This is the problemas @yagmoth555 said...